# Apple Certificates Renewal

Tags: ios, enterprise, mdm

I have an iOS MDM application which contains a set of restrictions to be imposed on the device. While a user enrolls a device , a provisioning profile along with a certificate is pushed on the device. Now the certificate is showing to be expired shortly. What could be the impact of not renewing the certificate. And how Can I renew the certificate.
Any suggestions will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

When the certificate expires, your app will stop working.  You can renew it by logging into your Apple developer account at https://developer.apple.com and navigating to the Certificates page - you should see your certificate there with the expiration date next to it.  There is no option to renew it, but you can revoke the old one and issue a new one.

Once you have the new certificate you'll also need to rebuild the provisioning profile to link it with the new certificate, and then load the new profile onto the device.